# int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to load pdf in webView

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

I a, saving a pdf file from the web locally and then loading it in a `webView`. In iOS 4.0 and 4.1, it gives me BAD_ACCESS error while in iOS 4.2 and 4.3 it works fine.

This is the code I am using:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"press.pdf"]; 

filePath = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]retain];
NSError *err =nil;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) { //if file already exists delete it
    NSLog(@"file is already there !");
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&err];
    NSLog(@"error: %@",err);
}
[responseData writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES];
[responseData release];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"file is  there");
    NSData *pdfFile = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path ];
    [webView loadData:pdfFile MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    [pdfFile release];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"file not there");
}
```

I tried to enable `NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled`, `NSZombieEnabled` and `NSDebugEnabled` but in the console I get nothing.
Xcode just stops at that line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

and states `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

I do not have any idea what it could be and where to look next.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if I comment the following line out it obviously doesn't crash because nothing is loaded into the webView.

```
[webView loadData:pdfFile MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: What's `responseData` and where do you `[[alloc]init]` it?

Comment: NSMutableData *responseData is where my NSURLConnection saves the data from the pdf. I do [[alloc]init] it in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out all the `release` statements as a start... if the crash goes away, start narrowing down which one is causing the problem. Also: you should really study autorelease, because in a lot of cases you are retaining unnecessarily in the code above.

If that doesn't work, try commenting out pieces of your code bit by bit to figure out where it is really blowing up (obviously NOT where XCode shows).

Comment: edited my post above, actually did all that what you mentioned, still can't find the problem. and could you please tell me where I do retain unnecessarily ? I am kind of new to Objective C. thank you

Comment: This line `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]` doesn't need a retain because it's already an autoreleased object. See http://vgable.com/blog/2010/05/19/n-a-r-c/ and look up narc on stackoverflow.

Comment: if this line is commented out : [webView loadData:pdfFile MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil]; it does not crash anymore

Comment: @bllubbor, so if you remove the retain directly after the crashing line, it doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: @Yar guess I don't get what you are saying. which retain after the crashing line you mean?

Comment: @bllubbor Sorry, I got that comment backwards :)... I just mean that you should comment out all `release` statements, particularly starting with `  [pdfFile release];` Also: it might be that the webView itself has been dealloced... how are you retaining that?

Comment: @Yar commenting out [pdfFile release] does nothing already tried that. and the webView is released in the dealloc method of this viewController so this also can't be it. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Yar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1017/discussion-between-bllubbor-and-yar)

Comment: @bllubbor missed you in chat. Please try commenting out the `webView loadData` line and replacing it with `NSLog(@"test %@", webView);` and see if it still blows up. If it does, the webView itself has been dealloced.

Comment: @Yar did what you said and tried it in a new project. works like a charm even the same exact code so the bug must be somewhere else! now I am pretty screwed but thanks for you help! I'll mark your answer as the correct one even it did not help me with my problem but this is the exact way you should debug I guess! thanks again

Comment: @bllubbor, suspect the project itself or the nibs. As you build each thing from scratch, you will see if an error is introduced at each step, or (hopefully) note some discrepancy. However, as we've both noted, since the thing works in 4.2, you'll probably not find any code differences. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it has something to do with the autocorrection within the simulator.

Simulator > Settings > General > Keyboard > AutoCorrect = Off